# How to change developer website in app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I am having troubles finding where to change the developer website. I think pretty much looked everywhere except the right place. Checked app store connect before submitting for review and the developer page.[This is located at the bottom of 'Information' in App store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkxXn.jpg)

Comment: Did you look at your app info in iTunesConnect?

Comment: opening itunesconnect redirects me to appstoreconnect and i think i covered everything there

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can find this property in App Store Connect (Previously iTunes Connect).

It's called "Marketing URL" and can only get changed with an editable version (which Apple reviews).

[image]

Comment: A classic "http redirect" (301) also works, for those who need to update that url without submitting an entire new app for approval, just to be able to specify a new "marketing url". I would like to meet some apple developers, one day.